# На сайте не работают модальные окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wp-plugin

Есть сайт `(cms wordpress)`, на котором я хочу установить функцию заказа обратного звонка при помощи плагина `contact form 7`. И хочу сделать в виде всплывающего окна. Есть куча статей на эту тему в интернете, советуют подключать плагины ***"fancybox"***, ***"easy fancybox"***, ***"easy modal"***, ***"fancybox for wordpress"***. С последним получилось данную функцию реализовать на другом сайте, но на этом при нажатии на кнопку второй раз, открывается весь сайт во всплывающем окне. С остальными вовсе кнопка ничего не открывает, ничего не происходит. Наверное проблема в скриптах или в библиотеках, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Когда в хроме нажимаешь Ctrl+shift+j показывает:

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачайте самый свежий fancyapps, залейте в директорию с темой, ссылки зарегистрируйте на js и css в functions.php с помощью wp_enqueue_style. Скачать можно отсюда, здесь же демо-примеры http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ вам inline подойдет.